# Can you make Counter not write-out "Counter"?

Tags: python, counter

So when I print the Counter (`from collections import Counter`) to a file I always get this the literal `Counter ({'Foo': 12})`

Is there anyway to make the counter not write out so literally? So it would instead write `{'Foo' : 12}` instead of `Counter({'Foo' : 12})`.

Yeah it's picky, but I am sick of grep'n the thing out of my files afterward.

Comment: then you shouldn't be using `str`. Try json

Comment: So you down vote me for being curious?

Comment: Well its a foolish idea, if your grepping files you gotta be doing something wrong

Comment: Clearly... says the microbiologist with a months use of python...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just pass the `Counter` to `dict`:

```
counter = collections.Counter(...)
counter = dict(counter)
```

---

```
In [56]: import collections

In [57]: counter = collections.Counter(['Foo']*12)

In [58]: counter
Out[58]: Counter({'Foo': 12})

In [59]: counter = dict(counter)

In [60]: counter
Out[60]: {'Foo': 12}
```

---

I rather like JBernardo's idea better, though:

```
In [66]: import json

In [67]: counter
Out[67]: Counter({'Foo': 12})

In [68]: json.dumps(counter)
Out[68]: '{"Foo": 12}'
```

That way, you do not lose `counter`'s special methods, like `most_common`, and you do not require extra temporary memory while Python builds a dict from a `Counter`.

Comment: Thanks, was just a random thought that passed through me on the ride home.

Answer (score 1):

What about explicitly formatting it into the form that you want?

```
>>> import collections
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0]
>>> c = collections.Counter(data)
>>> '{' + ','.join("'{}':{}".format(k, v) for k, v in c.iteritems()) + '}'
"{'0':1,'1':4,'2':2,'3':2,'10':1}"
```

Comment: Sweet, I like how this can be applied to alot of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't very elegant, but you can simply cast it as a string and cut off the first 8 and last 1 letters:

```
x = Counter({'Foo': 12})
print str(x)[8:-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change the __str__ method of the counter class by going into the source code for the collections module, but I wouldn't suggest that as that permanently modifies it. Maybe just changing what you print would be more beneficial?